# Numpy: How to replace a column in numpy array with another column? Why this emample doesn't work?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I would like to replace a column of a numpy array with another array conditionally, a sample example is shown here:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.asarray([[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[2,0,0],[3,0,0]])

print(t):

[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [2 0 0]
 [3 0 0]]

# replace
t[t[:,0]==1][:,1] = np.asarray([2,3])

print(t) again:

[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [2 0 0]
 [3 0 0]]

what I want to get is:
t = 
[[1 2 0]
 [1 3 0]
 [2 0 0]
 [3 0 0]]
```

After assigning the new value [2,3], t doesn't change. Does anyone knows how to get the new t?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `t[t[:,0]==1]` is `advanced indexing`.  It makes a copy.  The following `[:,1]=...` modifies that copy, not `t`.  `t[...][...] = ...` works only if the first indexing produces a `view`.  You may need to (re)read the basic and advanced indexing documentation.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj ! I solve the problem by changing advanced indexing to basic indexing.         loc = t[:,0]==1 then loc = np.argwhere(loc == True).ravel() then replace by t[loc[0]:loc[-1]+1][:,0:2] = np.asarray([2,3]), it's bit complex but lucily for my data it works.